# How to create dynamic buttons in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android, Can anyone tell me how to create a button like in the attached image where I can click on the star and it gets added to my favorites list in another fragment? [image]?[image]

Comment: Are you looking for UI help regarding that star shaped button or the code to display the favourite cards in the Favourites Fragment?

Comment: I'm looking for an UI regarding help.

Comment: I ll try to post the answer below

Comment: The answer is posted below. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a vector drawable under drawables.

***/res/drawable/ic_star.xml***

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#F00000"
        android:pathData="M12,17.27L18.18,21l-1.64,-7.03L22,9.24l-7.19,-0.61L12,2 9.19,8.63 2,9.24l5.46,4.73L5.82,21z"/>
</vector>
```

2) Add ImageButton

***Star ImageButton***

```
<ImageButton 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star"/>
```